# How to implement a Trait for iterables over double references to the same Trait

Tags: rust, traits

Let's suppose I have a Trait `Tr`, defined as such:

```rust
trait Tr {
    fn tr(&self);
}
```

I have the Trait implemented for some type, say `X`:

```rust
struct X;

impl Tr for X {
    fn tr(self) {}
}
```

Now I would like to `impl` `Tr` for any type which can be turned into an iterator over references to values implementing `Tr`.

I have tried this: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a88dc9c4daa5cc6655e8ed384e048f4)

```rust
impl<T: IntoIterator<Item = impl Tr>> Tr for T {
    fn tr(&self) { self.into_iter().for_each(|value| value.tr()) }
}
```

But it doesn't compile because `IntoIterator::into_iter` takes `self` by move and my trait only receives a reference.

With that, I attempted to make the trait take `self` by move as well and implement it for references: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d43cc4e43fb2cc4c0380142328aa4a5)

```rust
struct X;
trait Tr {
    fn tr(self);
}

impl Tr for &X {
    fn tr(self) {}
}

impl<T: IntoIterator<Item = impl Tr>> Tr for T {
    fn tr(self) { self.into_iter().for_each(|value| value.tr()) }
}
```

This compiles fine, but only works for collections which hold values of `X`. My goal is for it to work on collections holding *references* to `X`, e.g.: `[&X]`.

To solve this, I have implemented `Tr` for double references to `X`, which works, but looks weird: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5138b3bb0a285fae981b1faf36306bae)

```rust
impl Tr for &&X {
    fn tr(self) {}
}
```

This also doesn't allow me to call `tr` directly on instances of `X` as it was possible when using `impl` for a single reference: `X.tr()` and instead I have to put `X` behind at least one reference to call `tr` on it: `(&X).tr()`. This can of course be resolved by adding another `impl` for a single reference, but it increases the complexity a lot when I have many types that implement `Tr`.

The question is, is this the correct way to do this in Rust? Can I simplify the code in any way or get rid of the "take `self` by move" altogether?

Edit: Ideally, the result should allow all of the following:

```rust
X.tr();
[&X].tr();
vec![&X].tr();
(&[&X]).tr();
(&vec![&X]).tr();
```

Comment: *This compiles fine, but only works for collections which hold values of X. My goal is for it to work on iterables over references to X.* Um... [it does](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4c9cb3e5b7800aeaaa11795fa3c1beed).

Comment: @trentcl I might not have expressed myself too clearly there. My goal it not to have it work on iterators that yield references to `X`, but to collections holding references, such as `vec![&X]`. (which leads to iterators yielding double references)